# permission denied oracle logging into database

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

while trying to loggin in oracle 19c database getting the following error

[oracle@johns 19.3.0]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
-bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus: Permission denied

tried group permissions and bash still not getting . How to fix this

Comment: You will need Unix admin help (not in StackOverflow) on working with Unix permissions. It will require the x bit for public or for your group *if* your group is the same as the group owner of the software (typically something like `dba`).